# Facebook SDK iOS share photo ( FBSDKSharePhotoContent ) can not share applink

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook

I'm trying to share a photo using `FBSDKSharePhotoContent` and make the applink works but I bang my head to make it works.

My app is mobile only so the photos are not hosted on any web site.

I use this code to share the photo:

```
let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = currentHeaderImage
photo.userGenerated = false
let photoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
photoContent.photos = [photo]
photoContent.hashtag = FBSDKHashtag(string: "#Showflix")
photoContent.contentURL = NSURL(string: "applink...")
FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: photoContent, delegate: nil)
```

I generated the applink using the Facebook Developer site interface.

The photo is corretly published on Facebook but there are no link in the post. If I click on the photo it only open a normal photo on facebook.

I tried also using `photo.imageUrl`, I tried also `FBSDKShareDialog` without success.

All I need is to share a photo on Facebook user wall and if someone clicks on this photo it should propose to open it in the mobile app.

Thanks for help

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution, stuck on this today..(

Comment: Alex, as I understood Facebook API now prohibit to doing so. It is not any more possible with API V4+

Comment: yeah, here’s I answered to my own question https://stackoverflow.com/q/38525095/1527468